# c#, silverlight, check if field passed by ref has an attribute applied

Tags: c#, silverlight, reflection

In a base class I have the following method for derived classes:

```
protected virtual void SetValue<T>(ref T field, string propertyName, T value)
{
   //assign value to the field and do some other staff 
   ...
}
```

Is there any way to check if fieldVar has an attribute applied (for example DataMemberAttribute)?

Comment: Its a little confusing, is the "propertyName" the name of the field that it so be assigned?  OR is the "propertyName" the name of a property whose value is backed by the field passed into the method?  If the latter are you looking for `DataMemberAttribute` on the property or the field?

Comment: You could do your method cooler and simpler if you'd simply pass Expression<Func<TEntity, TValue>> then it could look like this.SetValue( o => o.Property, value);

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do that, except that it looks like you're also told the property name.

If you can find the FieldInfo of the field, then you can find any attributes, but not through the ref-parameter alone.

Comment: Yes, I have property name too. Does it help?

Answer (score 0):

Reading between the lines you have a set of private fields which back the values of public properties.  On some or all of these properties you some data attributes attached that you want to discover.

```
 PropertyInfo pi = this.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
 object[] dataMemberAttributes = pi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DataMemberAttribute, true);
 if (dataMemberAttributes.Length > 0)
 {
     DataMemberAttribute dataMemberAttribute = (DataMemberAttribute)dataMemberAttributes[0];
     // Do stuff with the attribute.
 }
```